# Repeat elements in an array twice

Tags: java, arrays

Write a method that takes a `String[]` array and returns a new array with the original array repeated twice.

For example:

```
repeatArray(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"})
```

Should return a new array with the elements:

```
["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: You are supposed to make an attempt first.

Comment: This is a straightforward one. Think of how you would do this on paper, and translate that into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)).

1. Declare a `String[] result` of size, equal to double the length of the source array.
2. Copy all elements from the source array to `result[]`, starting with the index, `0`.
3. Copy all elements from the source array to `result[]`, starting with the index, equal to the length of the source array.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test printing the result
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(repeatArray(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" })));

        // Also, test assigning the result to another array
        String[] result = repeatArray(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    static String[] repeatArray(String[] array) {
        // Declare a String[] of size equal to double the length of array
        String[] result = new String[array.length * 2];

        // Copy all elements from array to result, starting with the index, 0
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, 0, array.length);

        // Copy all elements from array to result, starting with the index, array.length
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, array.length, array.length);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[a, b, c, a, b, c]
[a, b, c, a, b, c]
```

Alternatively, as shown below, you can use [`Arrays#copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T%5B%5D,%20int)) to **combine the first two steps** of the preceding solution.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test printing the result
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(repeatArray(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" })));

        // Also, test assigning the result to another array
        String[] result = repeatArray(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    static String[] repeatArray(String[] array) {
        String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * 2);
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, array.length, array.length);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[a, b, c, a, b, c]
[a, b, c, a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way your teacher expects you to do it, not using any fancy libraries or objects:

```
public static String[] repeatArray(String[] arr) {

    String[] toReturn = new String[arr.length * 2];

    int offset = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        toReturn[i] = arr[i];
        toReturn[i + offset] = arr[i];
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

The code inside the for loop could be done a number of different ways, the way I chose involved the least amount of loops.

As other commenters said, you'll learn more if you try the problem yourself first and post the code you wrote.